# Raco manage package dependencies

Tags: dependencies, racket, raco

With javascript using yarn or npm, a user can update a projects package.json file and use `npm install`. This is a simple workflow that is easy to follow as it separates the deps specification with the actual installation.

Is there something similar with raco?
A user can run `raco pkg install` initially but if they want to add a dependency they cannot update info.rkt and run `raco pkg install` again since they will get notified:

```
raco pkg install: package is already installed                                                  
  package: <package-name>
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I can do what I want with `raco pkg update --update-deps`.